# Keras sequential model works on local machine, but AWS throws an error about layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-ec2

I have a sequential model set up in Keras

```
agent = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        layers.Dense(22, name="output"),
    ]
)
```

Trying to run it on AWS give me the following error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "single_player_keras_repeat_playthrough.py", line 30, in <module>
    layers.Dense(22, name="output"),
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 161, in add
    'Found: ' + str(layer))
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x7fb3fac02518>
```

This code works fine on my local machine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your imports? You are probably mixing keras and tf.keras imports, which is not supported

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy `from tensorflow import keras` and `from keras import layers`

Comment: from keras imports layers uses the keras module, not the tensorflow.keras module

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so I should be using `from tensorflow.keras import layers`?

Comment: You have to make all imports either from keras or tf.keras, its your choice